# Why was the DOS clock device renamed from CLOCK into CLOCK$?

Tags: ms-dos, file-system, driver

From [the Wikipedia article on reserved device names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS#Reserved_device_names)

> ... and the CLOCK$ (still named CLOCK in some issues of MS-DOS 2.11) clock device were introduced with DOS 2.0, ...

Why was is necessary to add a **$** character to this device name?
And why didn't they name this device CLK which would have made sense in a list such as CON, AUX, PRN, LST, NUL?

Microsoft advices against using these device names as filenames regardless of extension. Perhaps too many users couldn't resist having CLOCK as a filename?

Comment: What was the name of the clock application that was in Windows 1.0?   I'd guess there's a fair chance it was called CLOCK ...

Comment: @another-dave At least in Windows 3.1, I see the WINDOWS directory has a CLOCK.EXE and a CLOCK.INI.

Comment: I (mercifully) have forgotten the vagaries of the DOS FAT implementation. Wasn't it the case that if the filename was a known device name, any extension specified by the program was ignored?  If so, that's surely the answer.

Comment: @another-dave Except that would have been an anachronism, because Windows 1.0 was released when DOS 3.10 was already available, so it couldn’t have influenced the development of DOS 2. On the other and, perhaps other, older clock apps already started to appear (or were expected to appear)…

Comment: Related reading: <https://www.os2museum.com/wp/from-a-feature-to-a-bug/>.

Comment: @user3840170 Thanks for the link to this most interesting article. The very last comment there sums it up: "Not requiring the colon (which was allowed but optional) seems to have been the fatal flaw. Once there was no way to distinguish between a file and a device based on its pathname, there was just no good way out."

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Quick partial answer:

- **CON**, **LST**, **PRN** and **AUX** (*1) are names inherited from CP/M, either direct form its BIOS or CP/M's main file handling utility `PIP` (*2). **NUL** was add with DOS.
- DOS 1.x added additional names for installable interfaces like **LPT1**..**4** or **COM1**..**4**
- **CLOCK** was introduced with DOS 2.0

But DOS 2.0 added loadable device drivers as well, each able to bring any arbitrary name of its own. Basically not a big issue, but it would make it quite hard for MS to make sure that any *new* name they may come up in future versions has not been taken by any third party driver.

To solve this MS defined that all future (MS) device names, except for the DOS1.x like names, which may be present at boot, has to include a $ sign as last character (*3).

Problem solved - except, that definition was only made after DOS 2.0 was published, so CLOCK came preinstalled in DOS 2.0 without a $-suffix, a lapse  fixed in DOS 2.1.

**CLOCK$** was, BTW, not the only one added that way, so was **SCREEN$**, **KEYBD$** or **MOUSE$**.

---

*1 - there were a few more, like **RDR** (Reader) or **PCH** (Punch), that got added over time, but didn't make it to MS-DOS

*2 - CP/M [PIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripheral_Interchange_Program) in turn inherited them from [RSTS/E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSTS/E).

*3 - They had to pick one that had no other meaning at the time and would be valid wherever a device name is possible.

Comment: And RSTS inherited them from TOPS-10.

Comment: Incidentally, the 'symbols with a dollar sign are reserved to us' was also a DEC convention, certainly on RSX-11M systems (I forget about RSTS).

Comment: ‘To solve this MS defined that all future (MS) device names, except for the DOS1.x like names, which may be present at boot, has to include a $ sign as last character’ — where did they define that? Why didn’t devices like `XMSXXXX0` (HIMEM.SYS), `EMMXXXX0` (EMM386.EXE), `SETVERXX` (SETVER.EXE), `_doubleB` (SMARTDRV.EXE) or `MSCD0001` (commonly used with MSCDEX.EXE) obey this?

Comment: @user3840170 The keywords within the cited sentence are **present at boot**. CLOCK is such a a build in driver. Ofc, the same issue exists with loadable drivers, thus the 'fancy' names - which some even allow to be set (e.g. MSCDEX' `/D:xxx`).

Comment: It might be worth noting that the undecorated names- CON, LST and so on- all handle a stream of characters. That is not necessarily the case with devices such a CLOCK$, which generally speaking have device-specific interfaces access via an interrupt or locateable entry point.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd `CLOCK$` also needs to handle a stream of characters; specifically, sequences of three words. Try `COPY CLOCK$ CON` ;-).

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd CLOCK$ is a regular character device, thus ofc able to handle a character stream - in fact, it does even useful stuff. Just try reading it :)) Interrupts and 'local entry points' are not any interfaces to a device driver, that's what IOCTRL is for. Installing additional interrupts or chaining existing is about providing additional services, which can as well be done by any TSR.

Comment: Why make this artificial distinction between in-kernel and loadable drivers? By the time of Windows Millennium, the `XMSXXXX0` driver was integrated into the DOS kernel anyway (at which point they could not rename it any more). Was suffixing with `$` actually adopted anywhere as a principle, or was it just a bunch of ad-hoc decisions? Because if the latter, saying they ‘defined that all future (MS) device names’ should be so named is a stretch at best.

Comment: @Raffzahn Yes, it /is/ a standard device, but in this type of situation a name and the standard stream API (not that that term was in common use in the early 80s) is more a convenience than a requirement. And in DOS the ioctl() function was woefully underused: it was far more common to find that once a driver or TSR was in memory it used some proprietary interface... which of course is where the Blessed Ralph's magnum opus was important.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd The fact that hobbyist programming was rather standard in DOS can not really be used as a reasoning, can it?

Comment: @user3840170 It was integrated _afterwards_, so staying compatible is mandatory, isn't it. In general, arguing backwards isn't really of any merit - unless you'd own a time machien.

Comment: @Raffzahn Who the heck said anything about hobbyists? Look at the APIs provided by any of the big companies intended to access e.g. tape drives (QIC etc.), or intended to support graphics (GKS) or SCSI via ASPI. For that matter look at the extension APIs provided by IBM: I've wasted months sorting out control flow in one of those after they started shipping hardware that was /just/ too fast to run their code reliably. I can assure you that I'd have loved it if they'd made some effort to use ioctl() in a consistent fashion... but the truth is that they didn't.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Didn't say anything about hobbyists, but hobbyist programming - as in doing direct hardware access or peeking around memory when there are standard interfaces and procedures that would ensure compatibility. Working for a 'big' company doesn't rectify writing bad code, or does it?

Comment: @Raffzahn it appears to have escaped you that the examples I gave were intended to avoid people having to go direct to the hardware.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd It feels as if this is slipping. Point made by you was that drivers (of whatever kind) used proprietary interfaces instead of IOCTL, wasn't it? And that's the one my comment referrers to. It doesn't matter if these drivers tried offer a less hardware dependent access. Point it that they them self didn't follow the guidelines of using IOCTL as it should have been. (And believe me, I've been there, doing DOS since XT times, dissected (and rewritten) more than a few drivers - it was a well payed side job :)

Comment: Minor correction: The Punch 'device file' in CP/M PIP was PUN:, not PCH:. In PIP these names were followed with a colon to distinguish them from normal filenames; it was MS-DOS that put them in the same namespace.

Answer (score 25):

As Raffzahn [explains](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24253/79), the clock device driver was added in DOS 2.0. `CON`, `AUX`, etc. were device names already present in DOS 1.0, some of them even earlier in CP/M; these names couldn’t be changed to preserve backwards compatibility. Of all the standard (in-kernel) device drivers, `CLOCK$` is the only one which wasn’t already present in DOS 1.0.

An important subtlety in DOS is that opening a file or device ([interrupt 0x21, service 0x3D](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_kernel/213d.html) when using file handles) will open a device in preference to a file for any file name matching a device, *ignoring* the file extension. Opening `NUL`, `NUL.TXT` etc. will all result in opening the `NUL` device driver, not a file on disk. Thus, any new device driver effectively replaces *any* file using the same name, in any directory, regardless of extension.¹ CP/M required colons (`PRN:` etc.) to identify device names, but this requirement was dropped in MS-DOS, which merged the namespaces.

As far as the clock device goes, DOS itself doesn’t care what the *name* of the device is; the clock device is identified by a specific bit in the device driver attributes (bit 3). The DOS reference manual mentions this:

> MS-DOS assumes that some sort of clock is available in the system.
> This may either be a CMOS real-time clock or an interval timer that
> is initialized at boot time by the user. The `CLOCK` device defines and
> performs functions like any other character device, except that it is
> identified by a bit in the attribute word. The DOS uses this bit to
> identify it; consequently, the `CLOCK` device may take any name. The IBM
> implementation uses the name `$CLOCK` so as not to conflict with existing
> files named clock.

It would appear that the `CLOCK` device name was chosen, and then someone realised that it would create conflicts with any existing file matching `CLOCK.*`; to avoid that, the driver was renamed to `$CLOCK` in PC DOS, and `CLOCK$` in MS-DOS (which was also the name used in DR DOS), but not before some releases ended up using that name in the wild.

Without this change, people with files named `CLOCK.EXE` or `CLOCK.TXT` etc. on floppy disks would lose access to them when they switched from DOS 1 to DOS 2. `CON`, `NUL`, `AUX` etc. don’t have this problem because no one would ever have been able to create such files on a PC using DOS (except by modifying the directory entry directly on disk).

All this is the reason why installable character device drivers use variously-decorated names: `MSCD0001` and so on for MSCDEX, `EMMXXXX0` for EMM386, the list goes on.

---

¹ Ignoring both the directory and extension were deliberate design decisions. DOS 1 programs didn’t know about directories, and expected to be able to open devices anywhere (see [“From a Feature to a Bug” on OS/2 Museum](https://www.os2museum.com/wp/from-a-feature-to-a-bug/)). Some programs (particularly those ported from CP/M) also forcibly applied their own extension to whatever was provided by the user, so extensions had to be ignored so that devices could be used (being able to ask a program to use `PRN` or `COM1` instead of a regular file could be very useful in some circumstances). DOS supports a Unix-style `\DEV` virtual directory, but that never gained much traction.

Answer (score 5):

The `$` suffix was meant to fence off the Microsoft-reserved namespace. It works the way the `__` prefix fences off the implementation-reserved namespace in C and C++.

Similar to C and C++, DOS had a long legacy. The legacy devices inherited from CP/M and DOS 1.x were kept unchanged, as everyone writing custom device drivers would be aware of them. The MS-reserved namespace was there so that DOS-specific device names would not clash with those provided by 3rd-party drivers.

As for why some implementation-provided drivers, like XMM/EMS, didn't have `$`-prefix: they had a numeric suffix... This was another part of the device namespace MS has fenced-off for their own use. Those things weren't always written down, and absent a clear design documentation stating these constraints, the implementers often did things "similar but not quite".

Speaking of XMM and EMS specifically: the named device files wouldn't be used for anything but detecting the presence of the drivers. To use the services, you'd directly use service-specific entry points, e.g. `INT 67h` for EMM services. The name-based device detection was a bit more robust, as in some circumstances the non-installed interrupt vectors could point to garbage. The file-handle based access to performance-critical services such as EMM had too much overhead in the early days of DOS. DOS+BIOS made the decision to have quite a bit of system device access done by dedicated APIs, and not using the character device abstraction. Which, admittedly, was a shame.