# Windows/lanman shares ending with $ are invisible - where did this come from?

Tags: network, microsoft

(Inspired by a comment in an [answer about CLOCK$](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24253/10358) which says: the 'symbols with a dollar sign are reserved to us' was also a DEC convention, certainly on RSX-11M systems)

In Windows, network shares that end with `$` are not listed to connecting machines (for example, when use `net view`). This includes several pre-defined ones - `ADMIN$`, `IPC$`, `C$` for C:\ etc. - and also custom shares. Presumably, this was also the case with LAN Manager, from which many Windows sharing mechanism inherit their behavior.

Where does this convention come from?

Comment: Yes, this was also the case with LAN Manager, starting with 1.0; see for example [this reference in the LAN Manager OS/2 Administrator Reference](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_3Com3Open4anagerAdministratorReferenceJan89_9057290/page/n61/mode/2up).

Comment: As a general comment, operating systems often come up with some convention for "this name is not generally interesting, so we'll hide it from listings".  The dot convention in Unix, the H attribute for files in DOS, and the trailing-dollar-sign convention on Windows shares are all aspects of the same thing.

Comment: @another-dave with the caveat that the dot convention was an accident turned into a feature, not designed.